# install latest nodejs (4.2.1 or 5.0) on centos 7 using yum

Tags: yum, centos7, node.js

Is there any way to install the latest nodejs (version 4.2.1 or 5.0) on CentOS 7 using yum? Of course I could install it otherwise, e.g. from source, but I would like to keep it maintainable... And currently available in EPEL version is 0.10.36, see https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/nodejs.html

Comment: You could build your own package. The EPEL package will probably be on 0.10.x forever because of the whole io.js mess. Bringing it forward would break existing code, so they won't do that.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought this way. But I have never ever created a package. Is it complicated? (A link to some short tutorial would be perfect...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodesource provides repositories for both nodejs 4x and 5x.

For example, to install the repo for the 4x branch, run as root:

```
    # curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
```

Then you can install nodejs via yum:

```
    # yum install nodejs
```

Source: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

Comment: Note: the repo sits at https://rpm.nodesource.com/ It is a shame compiling node from source got so much more difficult now.